# Magento modules for front end static code in every pages

Tags: javascript, php, xml, magento

I made a magento module to include some javascript code and styles in every front pages of magento. Hence I add a code in config.xml file like following:

```
<layout>
        <updates>
            <common>
                <file>common.xml</file>
            </common>
        </updates>
    </layout>
```

In the common.xml file I located the .phtml file and in phtml file i put the code which will be included in all front end every pages.
I am not clear why it is not working or my approach is wrong.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What is not working? The XML file is not loaded because it's not found, it's loaded but has an error, the php script is wrong and why can't you even say if your approach is right? Why did you choose that approach, and why can't you verify it? And perhaps, just perhaps, [the Magento Q&A site](http://magento.stackexchange.com/) is of more use for such kind of questions.